# The item list it doesn't get updated with new item u add in the web page

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

this is my app node-js-list/app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var todoController = require('./controllers/todoController');

var app = express();
 //set up template engine
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 //static files
 app.use(express.static('./public'));

 //fire controllers
 todoController(app);

 //listen to port
 app.listen(3000, function(){
     console.log('You are listening to port 3000..');
 });
```

my controllers node-js-list/controllers/todoController.js:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var data = [{item: 'get milk'}, {item: 'walk dog'}, {item: 'kick some coding ass'}];
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

module.exports = function (app) {
        app.get('/todo', function (req, res) {
        res.render('todo', {todos: data});
    }); 
    app.post('/todo', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
        data.push(req.body);
        res.json(data);
    });
    app.delete('/todo', function (req, res) {

    });
};
```

My view node-js-list/public/views/todo.ejs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Toddo list</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My todo</h1>
        <div id="todo-table">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add new itme.." required />
                <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
            </form>
            <ul><% todos.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
                <li><%= todos[index].item %></li>
            <% }) %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this file of jQuery & Ajax to handle the http requests node-js-list/public/assets/todo-list.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form').on('submit', function(){

      var item = $('form input');
      var todo = {item: item.val()};

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/todo',
        data: todo,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
          location.reload();
        }
      });

      return    ;

  });

  // $('li').on('click', function(){
  //     var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
  //     $.ajax({
  //       type: 'DELETE',
  //       url: '/todo/' + item,
  //       success: function(data){
  //         //do something with the data via front-end framework
  //         location.reload();
  //       }
  //     });
  // });

});
```

Everything looks cool when u run the code, but when u try to add a new item by hitting the button "Add item" nothing happena

Comment: "nothing happens" are you 100% sure your page doesn't simply reload because of the form post?  change your `return       ;` to `return false;` and change the `location.reload()` to an `alert("test")` (or use browser debugging tools to see what it *is* doing)

Comment: nothing ever changes